# Highchart Bubble Chart Shadow

Tags: highcharts, bubble-chart

I have tried to this to put shadow on the outer layer of bubble chart but nothing is working.

```
plotOptions: {
series:{
  shadow: true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing it, it seems like a bug. I reported it on the GitHub issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13531